# Reading Custom Post data so I can have user update Manually

Tags: custom-post-types, plugins

Sorry if this sounds like a newbie question.  However, I am currently building a site and I am using a plugin called SportSpress and they create some custom post types in the there plugin.   I am Wondering is there away I can find out what data or fields they are using so I can create a form on the front end to allow users to update?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the database.
There are only two places to store data for a post type.
Let’s assume the post type is called FRANK have a look at the wp_posts table and run

```
SELECT * FROM wp_posts WHERE post_type = ‘FRANK’
```

The second place to store data is the wp_postmeta table. Use one of the IDs (e.g. 9999 in this example) you received in previous statement and use it in this query to get all meta fields for this post

```
SELECT *
FROM wp_postmeta
WHERE post_id=9999
```

You can also combine both with a JOIN but in my opinion it’s easier to understand like that